# Call a controller method from a view in MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I am new to MVC framework and here stucked with an updation method, can anyone help me?

MyCode in View :

```
       <table>
        <% if (Model == null || Model.Count <= 0)
        {
        %>
        <tr>
        <td >
     No Records found !!.Please search.
     </td>
     </tr>
    <% }
     else
     {
     foreach (var item in Model)
     { %>

     <tr>
     <td>Id</td>
     <td><%: item.ID %></td>

    <tr>
     <td > System : </td>
    <td >                                                                        
     <input id="txtSystemName" value=' <%: item.System %>' type="text"style="height: 20px; width: 120px;" />
     </td>
     <td >TaskName :</td>
    <td><input id="txtTaskName" value='<%: item.TaskName %>' class="TextBoxStyle" type="text"
    style="height: 20px; width: 340px;" /><td/>
    <tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input id="Submit1" name="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" class="ButtonStyle"
     style="width: 100px; height: 20px" /></td>
    </tr>
<%
}
}
%>
```

The above is my code and here i will get the records in the view and the above code doesnt contain all the property i have pasted only 3 fields and wen i update some names in the input field and wen i clicked the button in that table i want to update only that record values for this i want to know how to call the controller method and and to pass the parameters to the method.

can anyone help me for this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest you. Start with a view model which will represent a table row:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller which will contain actions for listing all models and updating a single row:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // I have hardcoded some data here in order to return a list
        // of models => in your case you would probably fetch those from
        // some data source
        var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(x => new MyViewModel
        {
            Id = x,
            SystemName = "system " + x,
            TaskName = "task " + x
        });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // This action will be responsible for updating the view model
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // The model is valid
            // TODO: update it using a repository
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        // there was an error => redisplay the view so that the user can fix it
        return PartialView("_MyViewModel", model);
    }
}
```

Then let's move on to the main view (`~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`):

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>>" 
%>

...

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>System name</th>
            <th>Task name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% if (Model == null || Model.Count() < 1) { %>
            <tr>        
                <td colspan="4">
                    No Records found !! Please search.
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } else { %>
            <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
                <%= Html.Partial("_MyViewModel", item) %>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then we define a partial for the view model (`~/Views/Home/_MyViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" 
%>
<tr>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "updateForm" })) { %>
        <td>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SystemName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SystemName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.TaskName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TaskName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </td>
    <% } %>
</tr>
```

and the last part is to AJAXify those forms. This could be done unobtrusively in a separate javascript file using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.updateForm').submit(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.success) {
                    form.closest('tr').replaceWith(result);
                } else {
                    alert('record successfully updated');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically have two Action methods in the controller.  One that handles the GETs and the other handles the POSTs.  The original page load is a GET, so that's this guy:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Tasks()
{
    // get your object/model.
    List<Task> tasks = DataAccessLayer.GetTasks();

    // pass your model to the strongly-typed view.
    return View(tasks);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Tasks(List<Task> tasks)
{
    // check if all model property requirements are satisfied.
    if (ModelState.isValid)
    {
        // ... update tasks...
    }

    // return updated objects/model to view.
    return View(tasks);
}
```

Also, you should switch to using [Html Helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx), instead manually semi-binding your model properties.  Then your model properties will easily map to the elements on the page.   For example:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
```

This would render something like `<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />` for the Name property of your model (assuming it's Task object).

One way to handle lists within your model (or the model itself) is to force the input fields' `name` attribute to contain index property of your list.  For example, check out:

[Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Another way to handle lists is to create a custom Html Helper for generic lists.  Here are some links to help with that:

[ASP.Net MVC HTML List helper](http://refactormycode.com/codes/1158-asp-net-mvc-html-list-helper)

[ASP.NET MVC 3 : Creating a Custom HTML Helper to Render List of Models as a Table](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page%3acreating-custom-html-helper-render-table)

I don't see your form definition in code, but by default the submit button should submit the form and call the POST method that passes in the model/object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My view will inherits a collection of TASK and here how can i get the edited record...Shall i use the Ajax.begin form method to update the record,if it is advisable means ,any code samples please....